# PostGIS: intersections of set of collinear line segments, with counts

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

I have a set of collinear line segments (may be mutually disjoint, contained, or overlapping).

I want to make a new set of line segments where the segments are disjoint or touching (not overlapping), and each line segment has a count of the original line segments that cover it.

For example, suppose the original set is (drawn non-collinearly for illustration):

```
A----------------------B
        C---------------------------D
            E-----F
                                           G-------------H
                                                         I-------J
```

the desired new set would be:

```
A-------C---E-----F-----B-----------D      G-------------H-------J
    1     2    3     2        1                    1         1
```

(only the point coordinates matter, the new set does not share point objects with the old set)

How can I achieve this with PostGIS?

Related question:  suppose I start with a table of line segments, not all collinear, how do I write the entire query that groups the collinear segments together and then applies the solution to my first question?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: let's make it one question at a time please and also post your table and some sample data please

Answer (score 1):

Setup (for later queries):

```
create table lines (
  id        serial               primary key,
  label     text                 not null,
  line_data geometry(linestring) not null
);

insert into lines(label, line_data)
values ('A-B', ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(-3, -6), ST_MakePoint( 1,  2))),
       ('D-C', ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint( 2,  4), ST_MakePoint(-2, -4))),
       ('E-F', ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(-1, -2), ST_MakePoint( 0,  0))),
       ('G-H', ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint( 3,  6), ST_MakePoint( 4,  8))),
       ('I-J', ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint( 4,  8), ST_MakePoint( 5, 10))),
       ('P-L', ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint( 1,  0), ST_MakePoint( 2,  2))),
       ('X-Y', ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint( 2,  2), ST_MakePoint( 0,  4)));
```

*Notes*:

- I purposely switched your D and C points to demonstrate a need for vector negation
- The `P-L` line is parallel with your example lines (but not collinear)
- The `X-Y` line has nothing to do with the others
- the solutions below obviously won't work, when you have *linestring*s that have more than 2 points and those are not on the same line (so when a single *linestring* is not straight).

The [`ST_Union`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/ST_Union.html) aggregate function can split your collinear *linestring*s. You'll just need to calculate how many lines are containing those.

However, grouping by collinearity is not that simple. I did not find any out-of-the-box solution for this, but you can calculate it (this will not calculate counts yet):

```
select   string_agg(label, ','), ST_AsText(ST_Multi(ST_Union(line_data)))
from     lines
group by (
  select case
           when ST_SRID(s) <> ST_SRID(e) then row(ST_SRID(s), s, null)
           when ST_X(s) = ST_X(e) then row(ST_SRID(s), ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(ST_X(s), 1.0), ST_SRID(s)), null)
           when ST_Y(s) = ST_Y(e) then row(ST_SRID(s), ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(1.0, ST_Y(e)), ST_SRID(s)), null)
           else (
             select  row(
                       ST_SRID(s),
                       (select case
                          when ST_Y(rv) < 0
                          then ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-ST_X(rv), -ST_Y(rv)), ST_SRID(s))
                          else rv
                        end), -- normalized vector (negated when necessary, but same for all parallel lines)
                       (ST_X(e) * ST_Y(s) - ST_X(s) * ST_Y(e)) / (ST_X(e) - ST_X(s)) -- solution of the linear equaltion, where x=0
                     )
             from    coalesce(1.0 / nullif(ST_Distance(s, e), 0), 0) dmi, -- distance's multiplicative inverse
                     ST_TransScale(e, -ST_X(s), -ST_Y(s), dmi, dmi) rv -- raw vector (translated and scaled)
           )
         end
  from   ST_StartPoint(line_data) s,
         ST_EndPoint(line_data) e
)
```

will produce:

```
X-Y                 | MULTILINESTRING((2 2,0 4))
P-L                 | MULTILINESTRING((1 0,2 2))
E-F,A-B,I-J,G-H,D-C | MULTILINESTRING((-3 -6,-2 -4),(-2 -4,-1 -2),(-1 -2,0 0),(0 0,1 2),(2 4,1 2),(3 6,4 8),(4 8,5 10))
```

To calculate counts, `JOIN` your original data again, where the splitted lines are contained by ([`ST_Contains`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/ST_Contains.html)) your original lines:

```
select    ST_AsText(splitted_line), count(line_data)
from      (select   ST_Multi(ST_Union(line_data)) ml
           from     lines
           group by (
             select case
               when ST_SRID(s) <> ST_SRID(e) then row(ST_SRID(s), s, null)
               when ST_X(s) = ST_X(e) then row(ST_SRID(s), ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(ST_X(s), 1.0), ST_SRID(s)), null)
               when ST_Y(s) = ST_Y(e) then row(ST_SRID(s), ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(1.0, ST_Y(e)), ST_SRID(s)), null)
               else (
                 select  row(
                           ST_SRID(s),
                           (select case
                              when ST_Y(rv) < 0
                              then ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-ST_X(rv), -ST_Y(rv)), ST_SRID(s))
                              else rv
                            end), -- normalized vector (negated when necessary, but same for all parallel lines)
                           (ST_X(e) * ST_Y(s) - ST_X(s) * ST_Y(e)) / (ST_X(e) - ST_X(s)) -- solution of the linear equaltion, where x=0
                         )
                 from    coalesce(1.0 / nullif(ST_Distance(s, e), 0), 0) dmi, -- distance's multiplicative inverse
                         ST_TransScale(e, -ST_X(s), -ST_Y(s), dmi, dmi) rv -- raw vector (translated and scaled)
               )
             end
             from   ST_StartPoint(line_data) s,
                    ST_EndPoint(line_data) e)) al,
          generate_series(1, ST_NumGeometries(ml)) i,
          ST_GeometryN(ml, i) splitted_line
left join lines on ST_Contains(line_data, splitted_line)
group by  splitted_line
```

will return:

```
LINESTRING(-3 -6,-2 -4) | 1
LINESTRING(-2 -4,-1 -2) | 2
LINESTRING(-1 -2,0 0)   | 3
LINESTRING(0 0,1 2)     | 2
LINESTRING(2 2,0 4)     | 1
LINESTRING(1 0,2 2)     | 1
LINESTRING(2 4,1 2)     | 1
LINESTRING(3 6,4 8)     | 1
LINESTRING(4 8,5 10)    | 1
```

Comment: thanks for solution. Now I try run first SQL query using real data (routes from OpenStreetMap) but receive error: "ERROR:  Operation on mixed SRID geometries SQL state: XX000". In database linear geometry in EPSG:4326 coordinate system. How can I fix this error? Example data in GeoJSON format [link](https://github.com/spatialhast/sh.route/blob/master/union_routes_line.geojson). Thanks!

Comment: @HasT you cannot mix SRIDs, so if you have data, with f.ex. SRID=4326, you should wrap `ST_MakePoint` calls inside a [`ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(...), 4326)` call](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html).

Comment: @HasT I've updated my solution to carry though SRIDs too. But I have to say: your sample data doesn't look like it has only straight lines. The solution for work only on those.